# I have a aspx file calling a static class with a static function. Is this thread safe

Tags: c#

I have been thrown into the C# world to do a quick project extension (meaning, I am a C# newbie)

I have an aspx file that has this section of code

```
try {
       //do something here.
 } catch (Exception e) {
     object response = ErrorResponse.GetResponseObject("012345", e.Message);
     WriteReflectedJson(response);
 }
```

Here is the class

```
public static class ErrorResponse {

    public class Response {
        public Error error = new Error();
    }

    public class Error {
        public string code          = "";
        public string server_time   = "";
        public string message       = "";
        public int    product_id    = 0;
        public int    sub_system_id = 0;
    }

    public static object GetResponseObject(string code, string message) {
        Response response          = new Response();
        response.error.code        = code;
        response.error.server_time = "SERVER TIME!";
        response.error.message     = message;
        return response;
    }
}
```

My question is about this `ErrorResponse.GetResponseObject`: `ErrorResponse.cs` is a static class and `GetResponseObject()` is a static function.

Is this a thread safe way to do this?

Comment: That depends on the method implementation.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Comment: That `catch` block scares me!

Comment: Yes, static functions like the one you show **are** thread-safe in a way you want it to be safe.

Comment: @kdmurray why did you remove the code `ErrorResponse.GetResponseObject`. Don't edit it if don't know what you are doing? I rolled back.

Comment: @L.B Didn't notice that I'd removed code. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: It was an edit collision with the OP. I tried to add the class back, but LB rolled it back. Not a big deal, just keep in mind later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the information passed into that object is accessible to any other threads, and this method is not internally accessing any memory that is accessible to other threads, so there is never any way for a call to this method to result in any observable changes to other threads, or to observe changes from other threads.

Answer (score 0):

If the method accesses static variables that may be changed by other threads, it is not thread-safe. If all variables are local to the static methods themselves or access to all shared variables are synchronized, e.g., in a `lock` section , you should be fine.